# AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles relationship

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using asp.net core 2.2.6 identity. I am trying to get all users that belong within a role but there is not any navigation property in AspNetRoles that return this.
How can I define the many to many relationship and get the users that belong to a role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UserManager<> provide that find users which assigned role.

```
var users = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("RoleName");
```

Also you can check the documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getusersinroleasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: how can I remove all users from a specific role? Cannot seem to find such a functionality

Comment: I took a look to documentation, I can't find a function which remove all users from a specific role. I guess you need write your own function about it.